# While writing a Js code in ts, I get this error can anyone pls tell what it is?

Tags: typescript

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.css']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }
  videoCardContainer = document.querySelector('.videos__container');
  api_key = "AIzaSyDN42NPfuuWarhz2JRiNZ-eqkZ_nvXKEhk";
  video_http = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?";
  channel_http = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?";

  getChannelIcon = (video_data: any) => {
      fetch(this.channel_http + new URLSearchParams({
          key: this.api_key,
          part: 'snippet',
          id: video_data.snippet.channelId
      }))
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        video_data.channelThumbnail = data.items[0].snippet.thumbnails.default.url;
        this.makeVideoCard(video_data);
      })
  } 

  makeVideoCard = (data: any) => {
    this.videoCardContainer!.innerHTML += `
      <div class="video" onclick="location.href = 'https://youtube.com/watch?v=${data.id}'">
            <div class="video__thumbnail">
              <img src="${data.snippet.thumbnails.high.url}" alt="">
            </div>

            <div class="video__details">
              <div class="author">
                <img src="${data.channelThumbnail}" alt="">
              </div>

              <div class="title">
                <h3>${data.snippet.title}</h3>
                <a>${data.snippet.channelTitle}</a>
                <span>18M Views • 3 Weeks Ago</span>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
      `;
  }

  // search bar

  searchInput = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementsByClassName('inputsearch')[0]);
  searchBtn = document.querySelector('.inputbutton');
  searchLink = "https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=";

  

  // For Tab
  menu = document.querySelector("#menu");

  sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");


  ngOnInit(): void {
    fetch(this.video_http + new URLSearchParams({
      key: this.api_key,
      part: 'snippet',
      chart: 'mostPopular',
      maxResults: 50,
      regionCode: 'IN'
    }))
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      // console.log(data);
      data.items.forEach((item: any)=> {
        this.getChannelIcon(item);
      })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    this.searchBtn!.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      location.href = this.searchLink + this.searchInput.value;
      console.log(location.href)
    })

    this.menu!.addEventListener('click', () => {
      this.sidebar!.classList.toggle('show-sidebar');
    });
  }

}
```

In the ngOnInit,

I get this error

Argument of type '{ key: string; part: string; chart: string; maxResults: number; regionCode: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | string[][] | Record<string, string> | URLSearchParams | undefined'.
Types of property 'maxResults' are incompatible.
Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

Comment: Welcome to SO.  It's never a good idea to include your api key.   Unfortunately, I can't edit your message, so please redact it yourself.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can understand what is happening in the last section of the error:

> `Types of property 'maxResults' are incompatible. Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)`

this means that the component expects a string as `maxResults` input but you are using a number!